# why my google cron job doesnt work automatically?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have the following google cron job scheduled to run every 3 minutes

```
cron:
description: South32-FTP-Push  
url: /
schedule: every 3 minutes
```

it is supposed to run my main.py and download some files trough ftp.

The cron job works fine when I test trough the cron jobs web interface but it doesnt work automatically every 3 minutes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I've deleted the file and created a new one, probably some problem with cache.

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be because the `cron.yaml` content you show isn't actually correct, the `cron` should be a list of one or more cron jobs, so it should look more like this:

```
cron:
- description: South32-FTP-Push  
  url: /
  schedule: every 3 minutes
```

Comment: Hi Dan,

Thanks for you immediate reply, I completed missed the "-" in my code above. My code is structured as list with "-" and still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you see the job deployed/listed [in the developer console](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/cronjobs)?

Comment: Is the symptom happening with the development server or when deployed on GAE?